# Get filenames of available image sizes

Tags: media-library

Example:

/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/xyz.jpg

This has 2 other thumbnail images that were created with it..

/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/xyz-150x150.jpg
 
/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/xyz-201x300.jpg

How do you get the filenames of these other images from the post id or the original image src?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
*** return_image_thumbnails 
*** - return a list of thumbnails based on filesystem report.
*** @param (string) $image - Original image location. 
*** @return (array) $results
*** @author Oleg Butuzov
**/
if (!function_exists('return_image_thumbnails')){
    function return_image_thumbnails($image){
        $extension = array_pop(explode('.', basename($image)));
        if (!file_exists($image) || !(@getimagesize($image)))
            return array();
        return glob(dirname($image).'/'.basename($image, '.'.$extension).'-[0-9]*x[0-9]*.'.$extension); 
    }
}
```

usage example

```
return_image_thumbnails(get_attached_file( $image_id ));
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in a non filesystem way? My media is stored on a cdn.

Comment: is a wp way you can also return sizes stored at `_wp_attachment_metadata` postmeta field. Take a look to get_post_meta($image_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', true); and take your data from there...